# ubuntu 14.04 won't boot: run-init: /etc/init: Permission denied

Tags: 14.04, boot, permissions, initramfs, etc

I think something I installed caused this. When I try booting this is what happens:

```
run-init: /sbin/init: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
run-init: /etc/init: Permission denied
run-init: /bin/init: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: how are you booting? it appears that root isn't mounted

Comment: I have no idea but it shows the grub page.

Comment: @do you have a LiveCD to verify the files it is asking for?

Comment: @ravery no. I don't have a LiveCD or usb

Comment: type "C" in grub to get a command line.  ls (it is an L) is the list command,

Comment: @ravery (hd0) (hd0,msdos6) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61670/discussion-between-user103292-and-ravery).

Comment: keep going. where is your install?

Answer (score -1):

Since I had the same issue during the last days, and there is no answer yet, and the other answered questions in this forum didn't help me so far with this particular issue (even though they helped with many other issues of course), here is my solution:

I set up a bootable Live-Ubuntu USB-Stick, and ran Boot-Repair (you can read more about Boot-Repair and the steps I followed here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Then I tried to boot and I got the exact same errors as you. Right after that I got a Kernel panic error.

Interestingly, even the option "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-35-generic (recovery mode)" under "Advanced options for Ubuntu" crashed.

I even tried to change the boot parameters of the option "Ubuntu". E.g. in the line "linux" I tried to change the "ro" option to "rw", but that didn't help as well. I also tried to change the parameters regarding the partition, but that didn't work as well.

What solved my issue was, to go into **"Advanced options for Ubuntu"**, and then to choose **"Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-35-generic (systemd)"**. Then my system started properly.

Greetings!

PS: Just as additional information:
I have a dual boot system set up: Windows 10 (MBR) and Ubuntu (GPT). The boot partition for Ubuntu is separate from the Ubuntu-OS partition.